# How to strore string in a array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is my code:-

```
{{  
...  
 fileopen = open("test.c");  
 for var in fileopen:   
     if var.startswith("//"):  
       var1 = var.rstrip()  
    elif var.startswith("/*"):  
        var1 = var.rstrip()  
      else:  
         break;

worksheet.write(i, 5,var1,cell_format)   // dumping the data to excel sheet.

...  
}}
```

Lets say in my "test.c" there are two comments line as below:

{{

// HI

// Hello

...

}}

List item

when i run my code, i got only "// hello" in excel sheet but i want both the comments("//hi","//Hello") in my excel sheet.

I have tried to append the data but its not working properly.

I think "var1" is over writing with previous one.
In such case what should i do. :-(

Please help.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Where is the `array`you mentioned in the title?

Comment: I was asking how to store a string in array.i thought that will create an array and store the strings in array and one by one we can dump the data in to excel sheet but i dono how to do that :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your indentation as follows so that it writes *each* line instead of just the last one:

```
fileopen = open("test.c");  
 for var in fileopen:   
     if var.startswith("//"):  
         var1 = var.rstrip()  
     elif var.startswith("/*"):  
         var1 = var.rstrip()  
     else:  
         continue
     worksheet.write(i, 5,var1,cell_format)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but now getting error like "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)".

Comment: Actually i just want to open "*.c" file and copy all the comments part and dump it to excel sheet.i could able to dump only last one not the entire. Please help. !!!

Comment: sshashank124: above code is creasing as the error is "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)". Could you please help me for this issue. Thanks in Advance.